# What is the correct format to specify RestartSec in service file

Tags: systemd

I came across a website explaining restarting a service using RestartSec and they specified the argument as

> RestartSec=5s

When I read systemd manpage it says the field is unitless but I have found some other examples online where it shows it similar to the line above. Which one is correct?

This is what I implemented in my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=RAL Argus Service
After=network.target

StartLimitIntervalSec=500
StartLimitBurst=5

[Service]
User=root
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/RAL/Argus/Hextapus_Base.py -bsi=15 -bm=1
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct. Omit the unit for a value in seconds or use a time span value with  units.

From [freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RestartSec=)
(or `man systemd.service`):

> `RestartSec=`
>
> Configures the time to sleep before restarting a service (as configured with `Restart=`). Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Defaults to 100ms.